# WebStorm stop popping up output Run window in LiveEdit mode

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, webstorm, liveedit

I am developing using `WebStorm` and its plugin `LiveEdit`.
So as I start changing some `SCSS` code, it starts to recompile all files and outputs an error, because I am still typing. 
[image]

But the most irritating thing is that `Run` output is popping up each time it compiles with an error and this makes my IDE to jump up and down, sometimes overlaying line of code is being edited.

So my question is it possible to disable `autopopup` of `Run` output ? Or maybe any other ways to hide this window. I can set longer delay, but this still won't solve the problem.

Comment: That seems like File Watcher -- so change "Console" settings there -- to "never show" I guess.

Comment: @LazyOne thx !! It works, I have not noticed this option in the settings. Please post your comment as an answer, with this image http://imgur.com/a/3taHT , I think it will be helpful and I accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Reposting @LazyOne comment on the question as a working answer:

1. Go to Preference > Tools > File Watchers
2. Select your watcher (most likely it will be `Babel`)
3. Click on the `Edit` (pencil) icon in the bottom
4. In the `File Watcher` window click on `Show Console` and set it to `Never`: Example - [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJ33o.jpg)
5. Click `Ok` and save